# How to clear drawn objects on the desktop background?

Tags: c#, winapi, drawing, desktop

I am drawing an animation on my Desktop background but in a layer behind the desktopicons. As shown [here.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus)
I am getting the workerw window with this code:

```
IntPtr progman = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr workerw = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr dc = IntPtr.Zero;

        progman = W32.FindWindow("Progman", null);
        UIntPtr result = UIntPtr.Zero;
        W32.SendMessageTimeout(progman, 0x052C, new UIntPtr(0), IntPtr.Zero, W32.SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_NORMAL, 1000, out result);
        W32.EnumWindows(new W32.EnumWindowsProc((tophandle, topparamhandle) =>
        {
            IntPtr p = W32.FindWindowEx(tophandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", "");
            listview = p;
            if (p != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                workerw = W32.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, tophandle, "WorkerW", "");
            }
            return true;
        }), IntPtr.Zero);
        dc = W32.GetDCEx(workerw, IntPtr.Zero, (W32.DeviceContextValues)0x403);
        if (dc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
           Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(dc);
        }
```

Drawing on this window (graphics) works fine, but i am not able to clear the drawn objects. I am actually setting the workerw window as parent of a form and i am drawing on this form, so i just need to clear it when it should change the window or something like that. Here is a picture of the form created as child of the [workerw window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4ugo.png)
As some of you said this isn't inteded to do, so are there any alternatives to create an animated wallpaper?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Desktop isn't yours to draw on. What if it wants to  draw itself?

Comment: It's not exactly the desktop, but it's heavy to explain. What do you mean by drawing itself?

Comment: e.g. when some installer created a desktop shortcut, or when the user changed the wallpaper, or changed system theme so a wide array of system colors changed as well.

Comment: Its actually not that heavy, but you are trying to do things windows is not designed innately to do. You will need to somehow get access to the message pump to catch invalidation events and a plethora of others, i'm not sure if that's even possible in user mode (though it might be) . good luck

Comment: If I change the wallpaper my drawings get cleared away. So is there any way to tell windows to reload the wallpaper? Also it has to be possible because there is an application which is called Wallpaper-Engine. It does use the same techniqe as i am using, but can also clear it's drawings.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the first place, but try the equivalent of winapi `InvalidateRect(0, NULL, TRUE);` to invalidate the desktop.

Comment: Who voted this down?  Can't see any reason to, myself.  Sorry phillip, SO can be a bit of a bear pit.

Comment: @TheGeneral I'd say it's more to do with how the shell is put together than anything else, but maybe I'm just nitpicking.  Anyway, I agree with you:  OP, good luck.

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Since you construct a cross-thread window hierarchy, are you aware of the consequences? All consequences?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, might hang the shell, maybe more.

Comment: There are only 2 safe options: `1` Enable Active Desktop and set an HTML page as the source, implementing the rendering in JavaScript. `2` Use hardware overlay support with source color keying, and set the desktop color to a rarely used color (e.g. `0xFE00FE`). Neither option is supported in any supported version of Windows. What you are trying to do is not safe. This is a dead end. Might as well spend your time solving a problem, that actually has a solution.

Comment: @IInspectable If i choose the first option, do i have to rewrite my code in java script. That would not be easy because i have zero javascript experience.

Comment: You can worry about learning JavaScript once you have gotten hold of a Win9x, 2000, XP, or Server 2003 license.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the answer. I don't have to clear it very often so i do just get the current wallpaper and set it again. Here is the code:

```
public static void clearDesktop()
    {
        SetDesktopWallpaper(GetDesktopWallpaper());
    }

    private static readonly int MAX_PATH = 260;
    private static readonly int SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x73;
    private static readonly int SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
    private static readonly int SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
    private static readonly int SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

    static string GetDesktopWallpaper()
    {
        string wallpaper = new string('\0', MAX_PATH);
        W32.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETDESKWALLPAPER, wallpaper.Length, wallpaper, 0);
        return wallpaper.Substring(0, wallpaper.IndexOf('\0'));
    }

    static void SetDesktopWallpaper(string filename)
    {
        W32.SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, filename,
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what @Barmak said (because I don't think he got this quite right), the following should do what you want:

```
InvalidateRect (workerw, NULL, TRUE);
```

You'll have to translate that into C# yourself, sorry.  It's too early in the morning for me to figure that out for myself.

The other thing that ought to work is to destroy your form.  The parent window will then get an update event and redraw itself accordingly.  In fact, thinking about, that's probably a better approach.

Comment: I don't know what the OP is doing but `W32.InvalidateRect(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false);` should invalidate desktop. None of this is recommended of course.

Comment: @Barmak Check out his code (just the last couple of lines), the title of the question is a bit misleading.  But your answer + my answer = complete answer,  I'm sure he'll figure it out.

Comment: I have tried both of these already and they aren't working, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @philipp In that case, I recommend you post your query back to the original author of that post at Code Project.  He can very likely help you.